# How to manage localStorage and/or sessionStorage when opening new tabs, refreshing, or closing the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The way we keep track of whether a user has a valid login is with a token in localStorage. However, when they close the browser and reopen it, this token still exists, and so they can still visit the site until it expires on its own. I have tried changing the token to a sessionStorage value, but it doesn't have the login token in a new tab. I've also looked at beforeunload, but that doesn't distinguish between closing a tab or window and a simple refresh.

Here is a list of things I want to happen and which storage method works for that:

1. When a user logs in, they can open new tabs and still access the site with the same token sharing across tabs. (***localStorage***)
2. When a user closes a tab, they can still access the site as well. (***localStorage***)
3. When a user refreshes a tab, they can still access the site. (***localStorage***)
4. When they close the browser, the token disappears. (***sessionStorage***)
5. If they re-open the browser, they must log in again. (***sessionStorage***)

How can I combine these two functionalities?